# How to show Microsoft list item to person, who has edit rights?

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

Hello I am working on a Microsoft Lists project and I want to know, whether it is possible to show an item in the list default view to a person, who has rights to edit this item but is not the author of the item. I have list permissions set to the following picture:

[image: Permissions]

Answer (score 0):

So I have figure it out. The only way how you can view desired list items is creating a new view in SharePoint lists and setting up some advanced access permissions.